# Guardar resultado de una función en la base

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Perdón por la consulta sigo aprendiendo sobre Python y Django y estoy realizando un proyecto de pedidos y su detalle, tengo el modelo Pedido, y el modelo Item que son los artículos, por medio de una función quiero realizar la suma del pedido y guardar su resultado en la Base de Datos. Actualmente estoy trabajando en el Admin este es mi código.

Model.py

```
class Pedido(models.Model):
cliente = models.ForeignKey(
    Cliente, verbose_name='Cliente', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
total = models.FloatField('Total', editable=False)
pago = models.CharField(
    'Pago', choices=PAGO_CHOICES, default='1', max_length=10, blank=True)
tipo_pago = models.CharField(
    'Tipo de Pago', choices=TIPOPAGO_CHOICES, default='1', max_length=10, blank=True)
create = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Pedido"
    verbose_name_plural = "Pedidos"

def __str__(self):
    return '%s' % (self.cliente)

def recoge_total(self):
    items = Item.objects.filter(Pedido__id=self.id)
    total = 0
    for items in items:
        p = items.producto.precio
        c = items.cantidad
        sub = p*c
        total = total+sub
        print(total)
    self.total = float(total)
    super(Pedido, self).save()
    return total

def save(self, **kwargs):
    self.total = float(self.recoge_total())
    super(Pedido, self).save()

class Item(models.Model):
producto = models.ForeignKey(
    Producto, verbose_name='Producto', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
cantidad = models.IntegerField('Cantidad')
Pedido = models.ForeignKey(
    Pedido, verbose_name='Pedido', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Item"
    verbose_name_plural = "Items"

def __str__(self):
    return '%s' % (self.producto)

def subtotal(self):
    p = self.producto.precio
    c = self.cantidad
    sub = p*c
    return sub
```

Admin.py

```
class ItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
model = Item
extra = 0

class PedidoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ['id', 'cliente', 'create', 'total']
inlines = [ItemInline]

class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ['producto', 'cantidad', 'subtotal', 'Pedido']

admin.site.register(Pedido, PedidoAdmin)
admin.site.register(Item, ItemAdmin)
```

Funciona pero no como debería al crear un pedido este aparece con un total de 0 en el administrador. y al modificar el pedido solo con entrar y guardar ya realiza la acción y me muestra el total.

En ese punto se acaba de crear el pedido..! como se observa el total aparece en 0.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Luego de modificar el mismo como se observa ya aparece el monto, ya busque las maneras de que ese total me salga al momento de crear el pedido pero no me funciona ninguna, es por eso que necesito su ayuda...! De antemano gracias..! 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, me parece excelente que hayas escogido Django como tecnología para aprender. Para ayudarte un poco a tu pregunta, tu código está correcto, pero lo que sucede es que a nivel del método `save` la primera vez no tienes relaciones (de hecho, hasta cuando llamas al super, nisiquiera existe `this.id`) porque aún no se guarda nada en la bd. Es por esto que al hacer la consulta de un item filtrado por el id no te retorna nada y te devuelve siempre 0. Deberías buscar la forma de pasarle los items como parámetros a la función y que no los tenga que buscar el mismo. Ademas que así es mas optimo

Comment: Gracias @GermanAlzate exactamente eso imagine que era el problema, la cuestión para ser sincero es que no se como enviarle los items por parámetros, nunca he trabajado una función sin utilizar el self y no se donde mas buscar ayuda para resolver el problema.

Comment: Por lo que entiendo no tienes una vista en la cual tratar los datos si no que estás dejando que el administrador sea quien los trate. Porque siendo así cambia bastante el asunto, ya que por sí solo el administrador primero guarda tu objeto y luego los objetos relacionados, es decir primero crea el Pedido y luego le asigna los Item. Tienes dos opciones: Buscar en internet como sobreescribir el método `save_related` y `save_model` para asignarle los items como te expliqué en la respuesta. O implementar Signals. Por no tener un ambiente de prueba, no puedo darte la respuesta precisa

Answer (score 1):

Para complementar el comentario que hice, te explicaré como funciona el método `save` cuando lo sobre-escribes.

Cada que tu llames el método `save` de un `Model` Django correrá una serie de acciones para guardar tu datos en la base de datos, de acuerdo al modelo. Es por esto que incluso cuando actualizas o editas el modelo se actualizan los datos tal como te pasa, porque siempre que se llama el método `save` va a hacer las funciones que lo pongas a hacer. Entonces te explico con código:

```
def save(self, items=[], *args, **kwargs):
   # la primera vez que se llama save sobre un objeto,
   # este no tiene id, porque en la base de datos no se ha guardado
   # es decir, según la documentación de Django, la primera vez hace un
   # insert y las otras veces hace un update
   # así que trabajar con `this.id` es inutil para la primera vez
   if items:
       total = 0
       for items in items:
            p = items.producto.precio
            c = items.cantidad
            sub = p*c
            total = total+sub
            print(total)
       this.total = total
   return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

[Aquí](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#how-django-knows-to-update-vs-insert) está la documentación del **-INSERT-** y el **-UPDATE-**

Lo que debes cambiar ahora es el cómo le envías los items.

Asegurate de buscar los items y cuando vayas a guardar lo haces así:

```
pedido.save(items=lista_de_items)
```

Cualquier duda que tengas, comenta y con gusto te ayudaré